# Connect in Wix external database to private AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, external, velo

is it possible in wix to link an AWS S3 bucket as an external database. I have some images stored in the cloud storage that update daily. They should be updated automatically on the wix page.

Alternatives to S3 would also be conceivable, it is only important to me that the images remain private and third parties can not access the cloud.

Comment: What do you mean by "as an external database"? Amazon S3 is a storage service, not a database. Are you simply wanting to serve the pictures from an S3 bucket? If you want the images to "remain private", how do you intend to authenticate users and determine whether they are authorized to access the images?

Comment: Thanks for your question. yes I want to serve the images from the private bucket. "external database" is not the right term then. the images, which are html graphics, should be public on the page and be visible to everyone.

I have already connected the graphics with a public bucket, but you can read out the link and then directly access the bucket, that I want to prevent.

I would like to make it like when you take files from "media", only that these are always automatically updated.

Comment: This is the nature of the Internet. The only way to 'protect' files is to run a back-end server and have users authenticate to the server. Then, the back-end server can generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3. If users do not authenticate to your website, then there is no way to determine who should / should not be able to access your media files. You can use `aws:Referer` to limit which websites can request files from S3, but this is easily faked.